# SQL Server calculating percentage with in a group

Tags: sql, sql-server, count, aggregate-functions, percentage

I have a temporary table which gives me these results.

```
Question      Option    TotalUsers 
Question1    Q1Option1    4             
Question1    Q1Option2    0              
Question1    Q1Option3    4                           
Question1    Q1Option4    0              
Question2    Q2Option1    2             
Question2    Q2Option2    2             
Question2    Q2Option3    2             
Question2    Q2Option4    2
```

Query

```
SELECT Question, Option, TotalUsers FROM @TemporaryResultTable
```

I need to calculate percentage of TotalUsers out of TotalUsers with in that question it means grouped by that question like shown below.

I tried in the below way but doesn't work.

```
SELECT Question, Option, TotalUsers, SUM([TotalUsers]) * 100/NULLIF(SUM([TotalUsers]), 0) OVER (PARTITION BY Question) AS 'Percentage' FROM @TemporaryResultTable 
GROUP BY Question, Option, TotalUsers
```

any help on this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use window functions:

```
select question, option, totalusers,
    100.0 * totalusers / sum(totalusers) over(partition by question) as percentage
from @temporaryresulttable
```